# How to access data of domain user from administrator account via google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am unable to access data of domain user from admin account of that user...I tried below url to make archive of domain user of google docs :
'https://docs.google.com/feeds/[userName]/private/archive'

and this url to fetch contact detail of domain user :
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/[userName]/full"

But its not working...Please give some suggestion or some another solution to do this.

```
for contacts, code is :
 function getContacts(user){
      var scope = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/';
      //oAuth
      user="user@yourdomain.com"

      var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_('contacts', scope);
      var url = scope +'contacts/'+ user+'/full?v=3&alt=json';
      var urlFetch = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs);
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Google oAuth
    //Used by getDocuments(user)
    function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
      var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
      oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
      oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
      oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
      oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey(consumerKey);
      oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);
      return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always", method: "GET"};
    }
```

Comment: See following answer on how to retrieve directory contacts: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/35880/29140

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written some code which uses Google Docs native API to access user's feeds. You may check it here.
https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/urlfetch-and-oauth/get-the-document-list-of-a-domain-user

The same concept can be extended to do other objectives which you have asked in your question

Comment: I tried this concept for fetching the contacts of user also but it gives error.
Request failed for returned code 403.

Comment: @Rishi, You are right. I followed the same approach but it is not working for contacts. I tried at oAuth2.0 Playground (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). It works for docs but not for Contacts. I am not sure why. You may post it to Google Contacts API forum.

Comment: Any advances on this, is there an issue open for it? I just tried @Rishi 's [script](http://blog.knoldus.com/2013/01/05/google-apps-script-getting-profile-information-for-users-in-a-google-apps-domain-2/) but it does not seem to work still.